# Cannot print/access trendnet print server with new Xfinity gateway

Tags: home-networking

I got the new Xfinity gateway for 2.4 and 5GHz network.

The admin page for the router is on 10.0.0.1

Before new router, my trendnet admin page was available via 192.168.0.1

Now when i try to access 192.168.0.1, i get page not found and trying to ping it, i get request timed out.

How do i enable the printing using trendnetprint server with my new Xfinity gateway/router?

Comment: What is your computer's IP address? It may be that your computer is on a 10.0.0. IP address and thus probably cannot "see" the Trendnet print server. You may have to reset the TrendNet print server to get it to get a new DHCP address, or you can manually set your computer's IP address to 192.168.0.10 or similar and try to access the TrendNet device again.